# response in json [object object]

Tags: json, aadhttpclient

Below is my code to get response from webapi i am able to get results as count is showing right but it coming in [object object] format how to get proper json below is my line of code

[image]

```
const userList: ISuggestionItem[]=[];
      this.props.context.aadHttpClientFactory
      .getClient('xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx')
      .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        client
          .get('https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxxxx?userEmail=xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
          .then((response:HttpClientResponse)=> {  
            
            console.log("First hit" + response)
                     response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
                      console.log("Second hit" + responseJSON.stringify)
                       responseJSON.map(function(item:any) {
                        console.log("third hit" + item.stringify)
                           userList.push({
                                "key" : item.Test1,
                               "displayValue"  : item.Test2,
                               "searchValue": item.Test3
            
                           });
                           
            
                        }) 
      });
     
    });  
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`[object Object]` is the default stringification method of a JS object. You can display a JSON string with `JSON.stringify(theObject)`.

Answer (score 1):

The response **JSON** is an object.

If you need to print the JSON object in console, you need to **stringify** the object.

Try the below code.

```
response=JSON.stringify(response);
console.log("First hit" + response);
```

This will work in your case. For more detail refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)